# Pandas, wrong datetime format

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df, contains a date of 2999-01-01, which doesn't match format specified.

```
    a date
prod1 2019/02/23
prod2 2999/01/02
```

when I use:

```
df.date=pd.to_datetime(df.date_DATE,format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

it returns error:time data '2999-01-01 00:00:00.0' doesn't match format specified

How to fix?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use parameter `errors='coerce'` for convert datetimes outside of [`limits`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#timestamp-limitations) to `NaT`, also is changed format to `%Y/%m/%d` because separator is `/`:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format='%Y/%m/%d', errors='coerce')
print (df)
       a       date
0  prod1 2019-02-23
1  prod2        NaT
```

Comment: @S.Gu - it is impossible, because maximal year is 2262, only possible solution is use `Period`.

Answer (score 0):

Since [`pd.Timestamp` is represented as a long of nanoseconds](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#timestamp-limitations), the maximum representable `Timestamp` is in 2262 (specifically, `pd.Timestamp.max`), so what you are doing will never work.

If you don't mind representing your time as a day-long [`pd.Period`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Period.html), you could use that instead. For instance:

```
In [12]: df
Out[12]:
       a        date
0  prod1  2019/02/23
1  prod2  2999/01/02

In [13]: df.date.apply(pd.Period)
Out[13]:
0   2019-02-23
1   2999-01-02
Name: date, dtype: object

In [23]: df.date.apply(pd.Period)[1]
Out[23]: Period('2999-01-02', 'D')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just something came across my mind:

```
import datetime    
df.Date.apply(lambda x:datetime.datetime.strftime(x,'%Y-%m-%d'))
```